# setISODate() by week number is giving incorrect month for the first week of the year

Tags: php, php-carbon

When I set date by week number of the year like this:

```
$date = Carbon::now();   
$date->setISODate(2020,1);
```

I then get `$date->month` as 12 when expect to get 1.

[image]

Is it correct behavior? Why in the case weekOfYear 1 the month is 12? And can I set that date by week number and get month 1?

Comment: First week of a year can often report the last month of the previous year ... Correctly

Comment: And how to get month which is 1? Write some conditions like  if ( $date->weekOfYear == 1 && $date->month == 12 ) { //set month? }

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thank you for the answer. Is this because ISO 8061 rules? Is it possible to config the date object to work like I expect?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using week number?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 sets of data - one by week numbers, and the other one by months. I need to create the 3rd one from them (so I loop through weeks, change date object using setISODate() to get its month and then look and get proper month's value). It works OK for week 2 and more, but I have a problem with week 1.

Comment: Show an example of these 2 inputs and the required output please

Comment: 1st data is : [
 '1' => [ 'feature'=>10,'feature2'=>15,'feature3'=>20], '2'=> [ 'feature'=>10,'feature2'=>15,'feature3'=>20] ] where '1','2'... are week numbers. and the 2nd one is month ['1'=>900, '2'=>900, '3'=>100]. I need to divide every values for week number by corresponding to their values from month numbers

Comment: and in the end ['1'=>['feature'=>10/900, 'feature2'=>15/900, 'feature3'=>20/900], 2'=>['feature'=>10/900, 'feature2'=>15/900, 'feature3'=>20/900]]

Comment: So as non of this seems to have much at all to do with an actual date, whay are you fiddling with the date

Comment: Because this data keys are week numbers and month numbers. It is stored in the database and I have a method like $this->repository->getValueFrom2ndSetByYearAndMonth($date->year, $date->month).  And it worked as I desired before a need to use 1st week.

Comment: Can you share more details? How is this list of "features" connected to dates? How do you initialize Carbon with these settings?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for your time and help. I've just edited the result set data a bit to show that every week should be divided by its month values.

Comment: Ok, I have no idea how you get the `'6'` result output

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to get, but the first week of the year 2020 started on 2019-12-30 so you get the correct result. What date are you expecting and why?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, '6' is week number when month 2 started and I need to get value 800 because it is month 2.  All data here is just an example, in reality it is more meaningfull

Comment: @Dharman I expect for $date->month get 1, not 12. And I don't understand why it is ok that the object's weekOfYear=1 and month=12 and year=2019 at the same time. Is it not confusing for you?

Comment: If you take a look at the calendar you can see that year 2020 started on Wednesday. So the start of the first week in 2020 was in 2019. All makes sense.

Comment: So year 2020 doesn't have week number 1?

Comment: It does have week number 1. Week no.1 in 2020 is from 2019-12-30 to 2020-01-05

Comment: Ok, thanks. But in the object created by setISODate(2020,1) I see that year=2019, and month=12. (as I understand it is because the start of the week). How can I create the date object by week number 1 for 2020 which will return year 2020 and month 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused with the concepts of calendar weeks. Officially the first week of the year is the one containing the first Thursday in that year. This means that week #1 in 2020 is between 2019-12-30 and 2020-01-05.

If you want to get the number of the month of the first week you must not look at the first day of the week but **you must look at the Thursday of that week**.

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$date->setISODate(2020, 1, 4); // 4 is Thursday
echo $date->month; // month will be 1 for every year.
```

This will give you the Thursday in the first week of the year 2020 which falls already in 2020-01 and therefore month is 1.

Comment: @user3471696 Sorry about the wrong example, I don't know what I was thinking then. The fourth parameter should be set to 4 so that you get the Thursday every time.

Comment: No need to apologize :) although the example was not clear, the explanation helped me find the right approach with the third parameter = 4. So I am happy :) But also a bit sad that this question will be deleted soon and other people will not find this answer with working example.

Comment: @user3471696 There is an accepted answer so it will not be deleted automatically. I don't see any reason for this to be deleted manually either. I think it will stay for some time.

Comment: It is nice to know.